# Dynamic custom email headers in mule emails

Tags: email, mule, email-headers

I'm trying to send custom email headers in emails from mule.

Adding a static header in the

```
<smtp:connector>
```

definition as

```
<smtp:header key="headerKey" value="headerVal">
```

is easy but I need to make the header values different for every email I'm sending with

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint>
```

Can this be done with Mule's SMTP component?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding a custom transformer to the smtp outbound endpoint.

```
public class EmailTransformer implements MessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
        ...
        SmtpConnector conn = (SmtpConnector)event.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("SMTP");
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.getCustomHeaders().put("headerName", headerValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The transformer reads the values in the variables and sets the headers in the transformer's process method. Not very elegant but gets the job done.